# Change the value of the state without using useState in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, textarea, onchange

I use useState to change the amount of textarea:

```
const [vancyValue , setVancyValue] = useState('');
```

And in onChange I pour the amount in vancyValue .

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setVancyValue(event.target.value);
};
```

Pressing another button adds characters to the end of the Vance string.

```
 const addVancy = () =>{
   // var myItemV = vancyValue;
   // myItemV += '$%A';
   // setVancyValue(myItemV);
   setVancyValue(vancyValue + '$%A');
 }
```

This is done, but when I write a value after adding '$%A' in the teaxtarea , the amount of the '$%A' changes to ...... ، The amount in the teaxtarea  with a split.

```
value={vancyValue.split('$%A').join('..............')}
```

When I change the value for the display, the actual value also changes. Does it make sense? Or I made a mistake somewhere.

```
<teaxtarea id="Text1" cols="60" rows="5"  placeholder="متن خود را وارد کنید!!"
   value={vancyValue.split('$%A').join('..............')}
   onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} 
/>
```

note:I just want to change the displayed value.

I want to display
instead of the value of

```
"$%A"
```

the value

```
"....."
```

to the user, but the original value does not change.

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do... Pleas show a concrete example, what does "When I change the value for the display, the actual value also changes"

Comment: @ Dennis Vash I want to display the value (....) instead of the value of  "$%A"  to the user, but the original value does not change.

Comment: Please share the code of handleChange function

Comment: I guess its due to synthetic events, you always should add a FULL reproducible example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Virtuoz I completed the code